# How to pass data from the combobox to commandbutton in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a mastersheet which contains the dates(of every Friday's) in a combobox. In a separate sheet(s) I have the all the dates arranged in rows. I want my mastersheet to read the date from the subsheets and copy all the contents for the matching row.
Currently I tried doing it by matching the system date with the date column in the subsheets. But the problem is that I cant run the program on any other day than Friday. So I want to the option to select the date from combobox and then copy the data from the subsheets.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  With ComboBox1
   .AddItem "Select Date"
   .AddItem "21-Apr-17"
   .AddItem "28-Apr-17"
   .AddItem "5-May-17"
   .AddItem "12-May-17"
   .AddItem "19-May-17"
  End With
 End Sub
```

(Content of reconcile button)

```
For Each studentID In master.Range("B4:B" & lr)
   StrFile = Dir(path & "timeuti*" & studentID.Value & "*.xls*")
   If Len(StrFile) > 0 Then
     Set wbtime = Workbooks.Open(path & StrFile, , 1)
     Set wstime = wbtime.Worksheets("Sheet1")
     With wstime
        Set finddate = .Range("A4", .Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Find(Date, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not finddate Is Nothing Then
            finddate.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 21).Copy studentID.Offset(, 1)
        End If
    End With
    wbtime.Close 0
End If
```

MasterSheet: [image: Mastersheet]
Subsheets: [image: Subsheets]

Also is there anyway where all the contents of the comboboxes are displayed when opening the mastersheet? Everytime I open I get only the select date option in the combobox!

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you want to copy and where to paste it? In your question is not clear enough what you want to do. It feels like information is missing.

Comment: I have a masterfile which runs the macros. I receive about 50 subfiles from my friends. I want the details from the subfiles to be copied to the masterfile. The masterfile contains a combobox that has all the dates of Friday's. The subfiles I receive from my friends have a column with dates for Fridays. What I want is when a date is selected in Masterfile combobox, the macro should look into all the subfiles and when the date is matched the entire row should be copied to the masterfile based on the id of the friend.

Comment: Ok. It is more clear now. However, it doesn't match with the description in your question. Please edit and fix your question! Also add where your problem is in the code you gave us (To be honest your code looks ok to me).

Comment: Set finddate = .Range("A4", .Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Find(Date, lookat:=xlWhole)   Here I am using Date as system time. But I tried passing combobox value there. It didn't work.

Comment: So, you want to replace the Date inside the Find() with what the user selected on the combobox, right?

Comment: Yes. Also I was wondering if there was  anyway where all the contents of the comboboxes are displayed when opening the mastersheet? Everytime I open I get only the select date option in the combobox.

Comment: As far as I know, No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the Date function inside the Find function with the value of the combobox.

You have to change the line

```
Set finddate = .Range("A4", .Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Find(Date, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

and make some modifications in your code:

```
Dim selected_date as String 'A new variable to store your combobox selection

'Store the selection so you don't have to check for every workbook you open
selected_date = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ComboBox1.Value 'Change the number to the sheet your combobox is

    For Each studentID In master.Range("B4:B" & lr)
       StrFile = Dir(path & "timeuti*" & studentID.Value & "*.xls*")

       If Len(StrFile) > 0 Then
         Set wbtime = Workbooks.Open(path & StrFile, , 1)
         Set wstime = wbtime.Worksheets("Sheet1")

         With wstime

            'Add here your variable instead of Date
            Set finddate = .Range("A4", .Range("A4").End(xlDown)). _
            Find(selected_date, lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Not finddate Is Nothing Then
                finddate.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 21).Copy studentID.Offset(, 1)
            End If
         End With
         wbtime.Close 0
       End If
```

If the selection in the combobox is in the same format as dates in the cell of the other workbooks you open and use find on them then it should work. Else check if they are the same format!

If one is in date format and because the other is a String you need to change the format of the date into string in order for this to work.

Comment: I get an error here : selected_date = Activeworkbook.ComboBox1.Value   stating that object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False   
selected_date = ActiveWorkbook.ComboBox1.Value  
Set master = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  
lr = master.Range("B4").End(xlDown).Row  
  
path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"`    These are the rest of the contents of my code before for loop

Comment: For the error, my bad, I fixed it now. Please check again. Also add the rest of your code before the for loop in your question!!! It is really difficult to read code in the comments.